# How to ensure all file shares of your storage account are backed up by recovery services vault

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I'm using a Storage Account File Storage to provide persistent storage option for an AKS cluster. To make sure the persistent files are backed up, I'm connecting the Storage Account to a Recovery Service Vault.

Also, I'm able to setup backup of a fileshare via ARM.

The problem is that with the usage of AKS and PVCs, the container deployment can create new file shares that are not backed up by the Recovery Service Vault automatically.

How do you solve this issue? I'm thinking about using a policy with auto-remediation or running a script in the automation account.

Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

*I have created the storage account*

*I have the some files for the clusters in the recovery service vault to backup the files of the storage account*

[image]

*I am having the two files below*

[image]

*On the recovery service vault click on the backup option and search for the which resources do we need to backup
I have selected the storage account and selected the files which have to backup*

[image]

*Once we click on enabled backup, validation process will start and backup will be created
When I click on the backup items in the Recovery Service Vault I am able to see the backup files*

[image]

*But when I click on the files we will see* ***Warning(Initial backup pending)*** *so for the click on 3 dots on right side and click on backup*

*Here we can set the retain backup time period  till that time it will backup the files*

[image]

*After setting up all the fields it will take 2-3 minutes to backup files and it created successfully*

[image]

*We can check the job status in below*

[image]

*I have used the default policy to schedule the backups for fileshares
In left side of menu click on* ***backup policies*** *and click on policy that we have to backup for time based.*

[image]

***NOTE:***
*While creating the storage account or resource group or recovery service vault the region should be same if it is different we can not add the any storage account and cannot automatically backup*